# OneLogin OIDC native application with PKCE refresh token expiry

Tags: openid-connect, onelogin, refresh-token

When using OneLogin OpenID Connect, for a native application with PKCE, how do I set the refresh token expiry?

What is the default refresh token expiry?

Can I have an application on OneLogin that does not issue a refresh token?

From the documentation, it looks like I can only control the refresh token expiry when using a password grant.

https://developers.onelogin.com/openid-connect/api/refresh-session

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct. Onelogin only supports admin control of the token validity lengths for the Password Grant flow. I have *no* idea why that is the case. No other OAuth2 Authz server I've come across has that limitation.

Comment: That's a shame. I wonder what the limitation is. This would be a basic feature that we would depend on.

Comment: They are expanding their OIDC support all the time, so the answer might not be the same in 30 days time.

Comment: Neat. I'll accept your answer and update this post when support is added :)